# mySQL select union query with repeated subqueries works slow

Tags: mysql, select, subquery, union

I have a simple table which contains pricelists (ID - of the pricelist, CODE of the goods, PRICE of the goods) indexed by ID,code (200 000 records) - At first I did it with "LEFT JOIN" but it works slowly, then I make it like this:

```
SELECT CODE,price FROM PRICELISTS
WHERE ID=1 AND CODE NOT IN (SELECT CODE FROM PRICELISTS WHERE ID=5)
union 
SELECT CODE,price FROM PRICELISTS WHERE id=5
```

IT works faster but not enough. Is any way to simplify the code to make it faster?

Comment: Not really sure what your goal is could you give a small sample data set and what your desired outcome is?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your query with UNION is equivalent to this:

```
SELECT CODE,price FROM PRICELISTS
WHERE 
  (ID=1 AND CODE NOT IN (SELECT CODE FROM PRICELISTS WHERE ID=5))
  OR
  (id=5)
```

which I believe is more efficient.
but if there are duplicates that you wanted to remove with UNION:

```
SELECT DISTINCT CODE,price FROM PRICELISTS
WHERE 
  (ID=1 AND CODE NOT IN (SELECT CODE FROM PRICELISTS WHERE ID=5))
  OR
  (id=5)
```

Comment: Yes, there is a duplicates that i need to remove. I need to remove the row with price with ID=1 when exists row with same code and ID=5.

Comment: If the ids are different then the rows are different so you don't need distinct. I assumed that your query with UNION returned the expected results, doesn't it?

Comment: Your SQL works a bit faster than mine. Thank you very much.

Answer (score 0):

Try avoid the not in and use left join for not matching values

```
    SELECT p.CODE, p.price 
    FROM PRICELISTS p
    LEFT JOIN  (
        SELECT CODE 
        FROM PRICELISTS 
        WHERE ID=5
    ) t1 on t1.code  = p.code 
    where p.id =1 
    and t1.code is null
    union 
    SELECT CODE,price 
    FROM PRICELISTS WHERE id=5
```

be sure you have a cmposite index  on table pricelist  on columns

```
 id, code, price
```

Comment: Thanks for the quick respond. Field code is a required field so there is no null value in it. When put "LEFT JOIN" the code executes slowly. I need to open the query quicker.

Comment: this mean that all the id = 5 return  code that match with code for id = 1 ...  the you have not a result for NOT IN  ...f

Comment: and for a quicker query  you should avoid IN and NOT IN clause  ..and use INNER JOIN and LEFT JOIN whit not matching  .. but overalla you need  proper ed  efficient index

Comment: when using Left join it takes about 3 sec. to open query - with checked SQL above - less than 1 sec. - speed matters to me.

Comment: Index also speed up. Thank you.